# Xamarin Forms(Android) - Upgrade and downgrade subscriptions

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, google-play, in-app-purchase, subscription

I've been struggling with this for a few days. I'm making an app that needs to support in-app subscription purchases.

I have tried the following packages:

-Xamarin.InAppBilling (Component)

-Plugin.InAppBilling (Nuget - beta)

-Android Publisher Service (Nuget)

But none of them support upgrading/downgrading subscriptions.

Are there any packages that completely support subscriptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have had a similar issue. These packages only support getBuyIntent. getBuyIntent does not support upgrading and downgrading subscription. The method getBuyIntentExtraParams does support this. With this method, you are able to specify which previous subscriptions the user is upgrading or downgrading using the skusToReplace parameter.

See the google docs for details: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html

The getBuyIntentExtraParams method is not available in these packages, but you can add the method in the aidl file of the plugin.

The aidl file of the Xamarin.InAppBilling package: https://github.com/hauptmedia/xamarin-inappbilling/blob/master/Droid/aidl/IInAppBillingService.aidl

You can download the aidl file and append the getBuyIntentExtraParams method to the aidl file. Add the aidl file to your android project and use it instead of the plugin.

The method definition:

```
/**
     * Returns a pending intent to launch the purchase flow for an in-app item. This method is
     * a variant of the {@link #getBuyIntent} method and takes an additional {@code extraParams}
     * parameter. This parameter is a Bundle of optional keys and values that affect the
     * operation of the method.
     * @param apiVersion billing API version that the app is using, must be 6 or later
     * @param packageName package name of the calling app
     * @param sku the SKU of the in-app item as published in the developer console
     * @param type of the in-app item being purchased ("inapp" for one-time purchases
     *        and "subs" for subscriptions)
     * @param developerPayload optional argument to be sent back with the purchase information
     * @extraParams a Bundle with the following optional keys:
     *        "skusToReplace" - List<String> - an optional list of SKUs that the user is
     *                          upgrading or downgrading from.
     *                          Pass this field if the purchase is upgrading or downgrading
     *                          existing subscriptions.
     *                          The specified SKUs are replaced with the SKUs that the user is
     *                          purchasing. Google Play replaces the specified SKUs at the start of
     *                          the next billing cycle.
     * "replaceSkusProration" - Boolean - whether the user should be credited for any unused
     *                          subscription time on the SKUs they are upgrading or downgrading.
     *                          If you set this field to true, Google Play swaps out the old SKUs
     *                          and credits the user with the unused value of their subscription
     *                          time on a pro-rated basis.
     *                          Google Play applies this credit to the new subscription, and does
     *                          not begin billing the user for the new subscription until after
     *                          the credit is used up.
     *                          If you set this field to false, the user does not receive credit for
     *                          any unused subscription time and the recurrence date does not
     *                          change.
     *                          Default value is true. Ignored if you do not pass skusToReplace.
     *            "accountId" - String - an optional obfuscated string that is uniquely
     *                          associated with the user's account in your app.
     *                          If you pass this value, Google Play can use it to detect irregular
     *                          activity, such as many devices making purchases on the same
     *                          account in a short period of time.
     *                          Do not use the developer ID or the user's Google ID for this field.
     *                          In addition, this field should not contain the user's ID in
     *                          cleartext.
     *                          We recommend that you use a one-way hash to generate a string from
     *                          the user's ID, and store the hashed string in this field.
     *                   "vr" - Boolean - an optional flag indicating whether the returned intent
     *                          should start a VR purchase flow. The apiVersion must also be 7 or
     *                          later to use this flag.
     */
    Bundle getBuyIntentExtraParams(int apiVersion, String packageName, String sku,
        String type, String developerPayload, in Bundle extraParams);
```